# Installation error: Expected Node js version >=14.15.0 but found 12.22.9

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, node.js

npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@20.9.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v115-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v115-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.2 and node@20.9.0 (node-v115 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v115-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.9.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.9.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.6 found at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3

I tried installing a npm package and I am not able to install it.

Comment: you're node version is older than the required version of the package, you need to upgrade your node version to get it works correctly

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! From the error in the title of your question, it seems that your node version is outdated. Have you tried updating to a later version, or use a different version through NVM (which is the best way)? Also, the error that you've copied would be way more readable if it was formatted. You can format it by enclosing into a triple backtick (` ``` `)

Answer (score -1):

Please try the to install that npm package forcefully using following command :

```
npm install package_name --force
```

for example let's say you want to install express and it's giving above error then you can install it using:

```
npm install express --force
```

Comment: If the package has a version requirement, it's likely to be due to syntax differences.